# Splitting the columns and append the values in the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe which has column as follows:

```
|REGION/CATEGORY|
|--|-|
|NORTHERN REGION|
|THERMAL|
|HYDRO|
|NUCLEAR|
|WESTERN REGION|
|THERMAL|
|HYDRO|
|NUCLEAR|
|SOUTHERN REGION|
|THERMAL|
|HYDRO|
|NUCLEAR|
|EASTERN REGION|
|THERMAL|
|HYDRO|
|NORTH EASTERN REGION|
|THERMAL|
|HYDRO|
|ALL INDIA REGION|
|THERMAL|
|HYDRO|
|NUCLEAR|
```

I want to split the column into two different columns in the dataframe i.e.Region and Category as column name.

```
REGION = ['NORTHERN REGION','WESTERN REGION','SOUTHERN REGION','EASTERN REGION','NORTH EASTERN REGION']
CATEGORY = ['THERMAL','NUCLEAR','HYDRO']
```

How can I write an if else statement so that I can get the following as desired output:

| id | REGION | CATEGORY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | NORTHERN REGION | THERMAL |
| 12 | NORTHERN REGION | NUCLEAR |
| 13 | NORTHERN REGION | HYDRO |
| 14 | WESTERN REGION | THERMAL |
| 15 | WESTERN REGION | NUCLEAR |
| 16 | WESTERN REGION | HYDRO |

```
for df['REGION'] in df:
    if df['REGION'] == 'REGION':
        df['REGION'] = df['REGION'].append('REGION')
    elif df['CATEGORY'] == CATEGORY:
            df['CATEGORY'] = df['CATEGORY'].append('CATEGORY')
```

I tried to append it to the columns after splitting

Comment: can you make column to text or code instead image?

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of simplicity I have used a list for the initial data.

```
data = ['NORTHERN REGION','THERMAL','NUCLEAR','HYDRO',
        'WESTERN REGION','THERMAL','NUCLEAR','HYDRO',
        'SOUTHERN REGION','THERMAL','NUCLEAR','HYDRO',
        'EASTERN REGION','THERMAL','HYDRO'
       ]

transformed = []

for elem in data:
    if elem.endswith('REGION'):
        active_region = elem
    else:
        transformed.append((active_region, elem))

df = pd.DataFrame(transformed, columns=('REGION', 'CATEGORY'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you...

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["REGION","CATEGORY"])
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['CATEGORY/ReGION'] in REGIONS:
        temp = row['CATEGORY/ReGION']
    else:
        df1 = df1.append({"REGION": temp,"CATEGORY":row['CATEGORY/ReGION']},ignore_index = True)
print(df1)
```

OUTPUT:
[image]

Comment: if row['CATEGORY/ReGION'] in REGIONS, what does "REGIONS" represent?